# Print chess unicode characters in C++, and make characters square sized

Tags: c++, unicode, console, chess

I'd like to ask what's the simplest way of writing the chess unicode characters in a console window in C++? (♙♘♗♖♕♔♟♞♝♜♛♚) They are part of the "Miscellaneous Symbols" block in unicode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

I also want to print characters with square size, right now my chess board is not square, because each character is a rectangle and not a square.

It'd also be good to be able to write with ordinary non-square characters below the chess board, but that might be impossible? To mix different fonts/formattings in the same console window?

Ok, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Very common question, put "chess console" in the search box.  Select the one that matches your OS.  Getting it square, meh, don't count on it.

Comment: You will need to choose a font that has the character dimensions you want. This cannot be controlled in your code (for console output).

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question, **outputting those characters**, is platform-dependent. Linux consoles often use UTF-8, if that is the case you can encode the characters as UTF-8 and write them to standard output. On Windows you can use the Console API (the [WriteConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function):

```
HANDLE handle = GetStandardHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD written = 0;
// explicitly call the wide version (which always accepts UTF-16)
WriteConsoleW(handle, L"\u2658", 1, &written, NULL);
```

One caveat which is hard to work around is that you need a console font containing those characters.

For getting **square cells**, this is dependent on a lot of specifics about the way the console renders text. If it uses font substitution, then there is a chance the text will not actually be monospaced.

Now, *if* you have a console font with these characters, and *if* that font is monospaced, then you may be able to draw a square board by adding some spacing between the characters. You can use block elements like `▌` *U+258C — LEFT HALF BLOCK* to draw the chequerboard: `▌♘▐█▌ ▐`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I'm using Windows. About the square size, yes, that might work, I will try! I'm a noob, so I don't know how to use the Console API in order to make this work. I've tried to google answers but I can't make it work unfortunately... Therefore it would be helpful to get a code example if you have one! :)

Comment: @user1066278 OK I can update my answer. Those are details you should put in the question.

Comment: Thanks :) Well, I got a square character, so I probably will have to install a new console font then... Anyway, thank you for your help :)