# Printing chess board with unicodes

Tags: java, unicode

I'm writing chess game and wanted to start with console version. At first I'v used simple chars to represent chess pieces, then I realized I can use unicodes. So I did

```
public void print(){
    System.out.print("   (#1)(#2)(#3)(#4)(#5)(#6)(#7)(#8)");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("(" + Character.toString((char) (i+65)) + ")");
            }
            if (!Board.getInstance().getTiles()[i][j].isOccupied()) {
                System.out.print("[ ]");
            } else {
                System.out.print("["+ PieceSymbolFactory
                        .getSymbol(Board.getInstance().getTiles()[i][j].getPiece()) + "]");
            }
        }
    }
}

static class PieceSymbolFactory {        
    private static final int whiteKing = 2654;      
    private static final int blackKing = 0x265A;        

    static char getSymbol(Piece piece) {    
        if(piece instanceof King){
            if(piece.getColor() == PieceColor.WHITE) {
                return (char)(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(whiteKing),16));
            } else {
                return (char)(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(blackKing)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatelly, empty fields are not working for me - instead I got something like this

Board picture

[image]

And if I add one more space in

```
System.out.print("[ ]");
```

Those empty fields will be wider than occupied ones. Is there any unicode I can place there or anything I can do to make both occupied and unoccupied fields have same width in console?

edit#
Ouch, Iv just realized that first line with column numbers is messed up too :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print chess unicode characters in C++, and make characters square sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123004/print-chess-unicode-characters-in-c-and-make-characters-square-sized)

Comment: [Drawing a chessboard with unicode characters](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/35804/43036)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple [whitespace variants in Unicode](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html). In this case I would try em-space (0x2003) or em-quad (0x2001) instead of the normal space (0x0020).